# Tooltip description on recurring events with same id

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I would like to display a tooltip with the description of an event on the eventmouseover event for a recurring event that has the same event id, but I only want to load the actual description in the json feed on the very first occurrence of the event.

The reason for wanting to do this is because some event descriptions can be quite lengthy, and I don't want to have to load the exact same paragraph 100 times or more and send that over the network if I can just access the first occurrence's description and display that in the tooltip for any of the recurring events when I mouse over it.

My calendar initialization code is:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
left: 'prev,next today',
center: 'title',
right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
editable: false,
allDayDefault: false,
events: "https://json_feed_url",
eventMouseover: function(e,m){
    var tPosX = m.pageX - 5 ;
    var tPosY = m.pageY + 20 ;
    $('#tooltip').css({top: tPosY, left: tPosX, display: 'block'});
    var tt = '';
    tt += e.id+'<br />';
    $('#tooltip').html(tt);
},
eventMouseout: function(){
    $('#tooltip').css({display: 'none'});
},
loading: function(bool){
    if (bool) $('#loading').show();
    else $('#loading').hide();
}
});
```

and my json data feed would be like so:

```
 [
 {
    "id": 0,
    "title": "Study Hall",
    "start": "2012-01-09T15:00",
    "end": "2012-01-09T16:15",
    "color": "green",
    "description": "Discuss formal language theory and abstract machines"
},
{
    "id": 0,
    "title": "Study Hall",
    "start": "2012-01-11T15:00",
    "end": "2012-01-11T16:15",
    "color": "green",
    "description": ""
},
{
    "id": 0,
    "title": "Study Hall",
    "start": "2012-01-16T15:00",
    "end": "2012-01-16T16:15",
    "color": "green",
    "description": ""
},
{
    "id": 0,
    "title": "Study Hall",
    "start": "2012-01-18T15:00",
    "end": "2012-01-18T16:15",
    "color": "green",
    "description": ""
},
{
    "id": 0,
    "title": "Study Hall",
    "start": "2012-01-23T15:00",
    "end": "2012-01-23T16:15",
    "color": "green",
    "description": ""
},
{
    "id": 0,
    "title": "StudyHall",
    "start": "2012-04-25T15: 00",
    "end": "2012-04-25T16: 15",
    "color": "green",
    "description": ""
}
]
```

This works fine on the very first occurrence of the event, but the remaining occurrences descriptions are all blank in the tooltip. Does anyone have a solution for referencing the first occurrence?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem in the eventMouseOver using a dialog. I setup a dialog box with appropriate elements w/ id's set then set the appropriate values as needed.  You could over course set those values ahead of time or when the page is loaded. (not that my code has 2 different types of appointments pulled from 2 different sources so the eventType is "appt" which is tested for in this case.

```
eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view){
    if(calEvent.eventType == "appt")
        {
        $('#eventDetails').dialog({title: calEvent.title});
        $('#eventDetails').dialog('open');
        var myDialogX = jsEvent.pageX + 10;
        var myDialogY =  jsEvent.pageY + 10;
        $('#eventDetails').dialog( 'option', 'position', [myDialogX, myDialogY] );
        $('#appointmentTypeName').append(calEvent.appointmentTypeName);
        $('#appointmentReason').append(calEvent.appointmentReason);
        $('#appointmentTime').append(calEvent.start);
        $('#appointmentTitle').append(calEvent.appointmentTitle);
        $('#appointmentFacility').append(calEvent.facilityName);
         }
         },
```